# Order Custom View elements by creation date?

Tags: pimcore

How can I order my [Custom View](https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Objects/Object_Classes/Class_Settings/Custom_Views.html) list elements by **o_creationDate** instead of the standard alphabetic order?

Thanks in advance!
/J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems this is currently not possible. The custom views query parameters are applied in this method and there is no support for order:

> \Pimcore\Model\Element\Service::addTreeFilterJoins

https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/master/pimcore/models/Element/Service.php#L750

The actual order parameter is set in:

> \Admin_ObjectController::treeGetChildsByIdAction

https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/master/pimcore/modules/admin/controllers/ObjectController.php#L106

The above is valid for Pimcore 4.3.1

Comment: Allright! thanks for the info. Will see if I decide to make a fork or solve it some other way.